# PHP jQuery: Append() to tabs is duplicating content until tabs are revisited

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I'm having an issue with appending content to 3 tabs that are part of the same container. For some reason, when I append the elements to each tab's container, I get a duplicate on each tab until I click on that tab and go back again.

Here's a sample of how I'm attempting to do this.

**TABS**

```
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="tabs1" role="tabpanel">
        <div id="container1" class="widget">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="tabs2" role="tabpanel">
        <div id="container2" class="widget">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="tabs3" role="tabpanel">
        <div id="container3" class="widget">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**DATA AND CONTENT**

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'data.php',
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {id: id},
    success: function(res){

        var len = res.length;

        $("#container1").empty();
        $("#container2").empty();
        $("#container3").empty();

        for( var i = 0; i<len; i++){

        var content = res[i]['content'];
        var isValid = res[i]['isValid']; //boolean

        $('#container1').append('<div>'+content+'</div>'); //this tab includes all results

        if(isValid){
        $('#container2').append('<div>'+content+'</div>'); //this tab includes only valid results
        }

        if(!isValid){
        $('#container3').append('<div>'+content+'</div>'); //this tab includes only invalid results
        }
    }
});
```

This example indicates that all data is in the same array and then conditionally appending to each container.

So what happens is that when I first visit each tab, I see the following.

"container1" shows everything but it also duplicates everything twice. (so, if I'm expecting 1 result for each tab, container1 should display 3 results but instead is displaying 6 (2 of each). In other words, it's displaying the content intended for container1 but also the content intended for container2 and container3.

"container2" shows the content from "container2" and "container3" until the tab is revisited, then it shows the proper content.

"container3" shows the content from "container2" and "container3" until the tab is revisited, then it shows the proper content.

when I revisit each tab, then I see the unique content for each.

I have tried pulling the data from different arrays (separating them on the server side), yet still get the same end result.

What I don't get is that the duplicates disappear when I revisit the tabs.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I don't have the implementation of your tab control I can only assume but I think it's due to the fact all your tabs have the `.active` class that will show all three tabs at once. If you have for example 6 items in your list with 2 valid entries and 4 invalid once, you will see a total of 12 items but they will appear in three different `DIV` tabs below one another. If your class `.widget` does not have an outer border or other separator, this might look like it is just one element.

Change it so that only one tab remains visible, e.g. the "tab1" tab:

```
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="tabs1" role="tabpanel">
        <div id="container1" class="widget">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tabs2" role="tabpanel">
        <div id="container2" class="widget">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tabs3" role="tabpanel">
        <div id="container3" class="widget">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: And you sir are correct. I completely neglected the .active class when I setup the tabs as I used one sample to setup the rest of the tabs. After removing the .active class from the other tabs, it all worked as intended. Thank you very much.

Comment: Great to hear! Copy-paste-errors happen so frequently that I always check for errors of this kind first ;-).